# How To Add Different Response To The Different Training Phrases Belong To Same Intent In Dialogflow?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I'm currently dabbling in Dialogflow. I have created an intent where there are multiple different training phrases are included & want to show responses related to the respective training phrase. Let me show you with an example:

I have an intent named "**company loan**". In That, I have added training phrases as mentioned below:

> *How to apply for bereavement assistance?*
>
> *What are the requirements for a Bereavement Assistance?*

So in dialogflow, How can we show different response basis on the question asked by user?
Is it possible to include two different training phrases in the same intent?

hoping someone could direct me or help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, [Intents](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents) are meant to handle different ways to ask the *same* question. They capture what the user *intends* to ask.

So statements such as

- How do I apply for bereavement assistance?
- What is the application process for bereavement assistance?
- How do I get assistance in the case of bereavement?

All mean the same thing - you'll give the same answer for all of them and they should all be training phrases for the same Intent.

While statements like

- What are the requirements for bereavement assistance?
- What prerequisites are there for bereavement assistance?

or even "What are the requirements?" if they're already talking about bereavement all mean something different and belong under a different Intent.

Sometimes you can use parameters if they're asking the same thing, but *about* something different. So

- How do I apply for annual leave?

might be handled with the same Intent as the first one - they're trying to get application information about something else. In this case, you could use a parameter for the "annual leave" and "bereavement assistance" part which you'd create a custom [Entity](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities) for. You can then use [fulfillment](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment) to get the response.

Comment: Thank you Prisoner!! Let me try & will get back to you if i get any issue.

Comment: Hope it helps! If you do have issues, feel free to open a new question with as much information as you can provide.